# How to get events/observers in magento 2

Tags: event-observer, magento2, magento2-dev-beta

In Magento 1 I can get list of events/observers by debugging `dispatchEvent()` method from `Mage.php` like below.

```
/**
     * Dispatch event
     *
     * Calls all observer callbacks registered for this event
     * and multiple observers matching event name pattern
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param array $data
     * @return Mage_Core_Model_App
     */
    public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
    {
        Mage::log($name,null,'Events');
        Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
        $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
        Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
        return $result;
    }
```

In magento 2 where I can get list of events/observers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do the same thing you did in Magento 1.x in the method `\Magento\Framework\Event\Manager::dispatch()`.

but it's a difference. You don't have access to the logger.
You will have to inject an instance of the logger in the constructor.

```
protected $logger;

public function __construct(
    InvokerInterface $invoker, 
    ConfigInterface $eventConfig,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
)
{
    $this->_invoker = $invoker;
    $this->_eventConfig = $eventConfig;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

Then you can call in the `dispatch` method this:

```
$this->logger->info($message);
```

Instead of `info` you can use all the methods from `\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface`

Comment: You are rocking........

Comment: @Marius just a typo with keyword $protected instead of protected $logger.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is for "quick debugging", you could avoid multiple edits by doing.

```
public function dispatch($eventName, array $data = [])
{
    $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
    $logger->info($eventName);
    ...
```

Location

> /lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager.php

*@Marius answer is the correct solution.*

Comment: Use `\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class` please. Always.

Comment: @nevvermind .. I tried that before ...  `Fatal error: Non-static method Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::info() cannot be called statically`. Please let me know if you figure out an easier way.

Comment: I'm talking about the [::class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) keyword instead of the _literal string_ FQCN.

Comment: Just get the idea here, instead of modifying the core. In other words, create a before/after Plugin for the above method, inject your Logger, and be happy. :)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I can get list of all event by doing below changes which is very short cut like we do in mage.php file of magento1:

Note: I have only tested on magento2.1.1 version so I am not sure for any other version

```
\vendor\magento\framework\Event\Manager.php

public function dispatch
```

write below code to get all event in debug.log file after

```
$eventName = mb_strtolower($eventName);
```

near to line 56

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug($eventName);
```