# Order confirmation observer in Magento 2 not working

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer

I'm implementing extension for Magento 2. I've been trying to add observer for event *sales_order_save_commit_after* but for some reason the observer doesn't catch the event. I've added logging for the events based on these instructions: [How to get events/observers in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86500/how-to-get-events-observers-in-magento-2) and it seems the event gets fired but is not catched by the observer.

Here's the frontend/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_save_commit_after">
        <observer name="my_dummy_observer" instance="My\Plugin\Model\Observers\Dummy" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And here's the observer

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Dummy implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent()->getName();
        $this->_logger->info("\n" . '[OBSERVER EVENT CATCHED]: ' . $event . "\n");
    }
}
```

Any idea why the event is not catched with that configuration?

Comment: Are you missing a namespace declaration at the top of the class file or have you just forgotten to paste it in here?

Comment: The namespace is in the actual source file. The observer itself works fine if a hook it for some common event like catalog_product_collection_load_after

Answer (score 3):

I figured out this one by myself. Apparently you cannot catch this event (sales_order_save_commit_after) from frontend (app/code/My/Plugin/etc/frontend/events.xml) but you need to have the observer defined in "root" level (app/code/My/Plugin/etc/events.xml)

Comment: FYI, `<event name="sales_order_save_commit_after">` will not work for guest checkouts (not logged in user)